# Why does the class definition's metaclass keyword argument accept a callable?

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, metaclass

### Background

The Python 3 [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html#determining-the-appropriate-metaclass) clearly describes how the metaclass of a class is determined:

> - if no bases and no explicit metaclass are given, then type() is used
> - if an explicit metaclass is given and it is not an instance of type(), then it is used directly as the metaclass
> - if an instance of type() is given as the explicit metaclass, or bases are defined, then the most derived metaclass is used

Therefore, according to the second rule, it is possible to specify a metaclass using a callable.  E.g.,

```
class MyMetaclass(type):
    pass

def metaclass_callable(name, bases, namespace):
    print("Called with", name)
    return MyMetaclass(name, bases, namespace)

class MyClass(metaclass=metaclass_callable):
    pass

class MyDerived(MyClass):
    pass

print(type(MyClass), type(MyDerived))
```

### Question 1

Is the metaclass of `MyClass`: `metaclass_callable` or `MyMetaclass`?  The second rule in the documentation says that the provided callable "is used directly as the metaclass".  However, it seems to make more sense to say that the metaclass is `MyMetaclass` since

- `MyClass` and `MyDerived` have type `MyMetaclass`,
- `metaclass_callable` is called once and then appears to be unrecoverable,
- derived classes do not use (as far as I can tell) `metaclass_callable` in any way (they use `MyMetaclass`).

### Question 2

Is there anything you can do with a callable that you can't do with an instance of `type`?  What is the purpose of accepting an arbitrary callable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding your first question the metaclass should be `MyMetaclass` (which it's so):

```
In [7]: print(type(MyClass), type(MyDerived))
<class '__main__.MyMetaclass'> <class '__main__.MyMetaclass'>
```

The reason is that if the metaclass is not an instance of type python calls the methaclass by passing these arguments to it `name, bases, ns, **kwds` (see `new_class`) and since you are returning your real metaclass in that function it gets the correct type for metaclass.

And about the second question:

> What is the purpose of accepting an arbitrary callable?

There is no special purpose, **it's actually the nature of metaclasses** which is because that making an instance from a class always calls the metaclass by calling it's `__call__` method:

```
Metaclass.__call__()
```

Which means that you can pass any callable as your metaclass. So for example if you test it with a nested function the result will still be the same:

```
In [21]: def metaclass_callable(name, bases, namespace):
             def inner():
                 return MyMetaclass(name, bases, namespace)
             return inner()
   ....: 

In [22]: class MyClass(metaclass=metaclass_callable):
             pass
   ....: 

In [23]: print(type(MyClass), type(MyDerived))
<class '__main__.MyMetaclass'> <class '__main__.MyMetaclass'>
```

---

For more info here is how Python crates a class:

It calls the `new_class` function which it calls `prepare_class` inside itself, then as you can see inside the `prepare_class` python calls the `__prepare__` method of the appropriate metaclass, beside of finding the proper meta (using `_calculate_meta` function ) and creating the appropriate namespace for the class.

So all in one here is the hierarchy of executing a metacalss's methods:

1. `__prepare__` <sup>1</sup>
2. `__call__`
3. `__new__`
4. `__init__`

And here is the source code:

```
# Provide a PEP 3115 compliant mechanism for class creation
def new_class(name, bases=(), kwds=None, exec_body=None):
    """Create a class object dynamically using the appropriate metaclass."""
    meta, ns, kwds = prepare_class(name, bases, kwds)
    if exec_body is not None:
        exec_body(ns)
    return meta(name, bases, ns, **kwds)

def prepare_class(name, bases=(), kwds=None):
    """Call the __prepare__ method of the appropriate metaclass.

    Returns (metaclass, namespace, kwds) as a 3-tuple

    *metaclass* is the appropriate metaclass
    *namespace* is the prepared class namespace
    *kwds* is an updated copy of the passed in kwds argument with any
    'metaclass' entry removed. If no kwds argument is passed in, this will
    be an empty dict.
    """
    if kwds is None:
        kwds = {}
    else:
        kwds = dict(kwds) # Don't alter the provided mapping
    if 'metaclass' in kwds:
        meta = kwds.pop('metaclass')
    else:
        if bases:
            meta = type(bases[0])
        else:
            meta = type
    if isinstance(meta, type):
        # when meta is a type, we first determine the most-derived metaclass
        # instead of invoking the initial candidate directly
        meta = _calculate_meta(meta, bases)
    if hasattr(meta, '__prepare__'):
        ns = meta.__prepare__(name, bases, **kwds)
    else:
        ns = {}
    return meta, ns, kwds


def _calculate_meta(meta, bases):
    """Calculate the most derived metaclass."""
    winner = meta
    for base in bases:
        base_meta = type(base)
        if issubclass(winner, base_meta):
            continue
        if issubclass(base_meta, winner):
            winner = base_meta
            continue
        # else:
        raise TypeError("metaclass conflict: "
                        "the metaclass of a derived class "
                        "must be a (non-strict) subclass "
                        "of the metaclasses of all its bases")
    return winner
```

---

<sub>1. Note that it get called implicitly inside the *new_class* function and before the return.</sub>

Comment: For question 2, I don't understand how you're answering my question: "Is there anything you can do with a callable that you can't do with an instance of `type`? What is the purpose of accepting an arbitrary callable?"

Comment: @NeilG As I updated, there is no special purpose, it's just the nature of mtaclasses.

Comment: That seems to suggest that you can bypass `_calculate_meta`, but I wasn't able to do that.

Comment: @NeilG Yeas it's for python 3. If you bypass that you won't get a proper meta as it's said in doc.

Comment: I mean, I wasn't able to bypass it by specifying a non-type metaclass.   (I still trigger the appropriate error).

Comment: using a callable: `class OtherDerived(MyClass, metaclass=other_metaclass_callable):
    pass`

Comment: @NeilG This is a different thing, I think you've ended up with a `metaclass conflict` which is because of that, the metaclass of your derived class is not a subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases. As the last traceback is saying.

Comment: But that gets checked `_calculate_meta`, which should be skipped when `meta` is not an instance of `type` (a regular function is not an instance of `type`).

Comment: I figured it out.  This is because something happened along the way and Objects/typeobject.c:type_new no longer coincides with Lib/types.py:new_class.  The Python version conditionally calls _calculate_meta whereas the C version calls it unconditionally.  I consider the C implementation to be the "correct" version.

Comment: @NeilG In that case it will run the function and since you are calling a class inside that function (with the same metaclass as one of the base classes) it will raise a `conflict`.

Comment: @NeilG I'm not sure if it runs the C code before the python code here. As I said it might be because after calling the class within the function.

Comment: It doesn't run the Python code at all.  It just calls the C implementation, which is inconsistent.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the `type` is of course `MyMetaClass`. `metaclass_callable` is initially 'selected' as the metaclass since [it's been specified in the `metaclass` kwarg](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/bltinmodule.c#L100) and as such, it's `__call__` (a simple function call) is going to be performed.

It just so happens that calling it will `print` and then invoke `MyMetaClass.__call__` (which calls `type.__call__` since `__call__` hasn't been overridden for `MyMetaClass`). [*There* the assignment of `cls.__class__` is made](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/typeobject.c#L2693) to `MyMetaClass`.

> `metaclass_callable` is called once and then appears to be unrecoverable

Yes, it is only initially invoked and then hands control over to `MyMetaClass`. I'm not aware of any class attribute that keeps that information around.

> derived classes do not use (as far as I can tell) `metaclass_callable` in any way.

Nope, if no `metaclass` is explicitly defined, [the best match for the metaclasses of `bases`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/bltinmodule.c#L130) (here `MyClass`) will be used (resulting in `MyMetaClass`).

---

As for question `2`, pretty sure everything you can do with a callable is also possible by using an instance of type with `__call__` overridden accordingly. As to *why*, you might not want to go full blown class-creation if you simply want to make minor changes when actually creating a class.

Comment: Of the two choices I gave, what is your answer to question one?  As for your answer to question 2, can you give an example where using a callable is somehow "less full blown" than deriving from `type`?

Answer (score 2):

Concerning question 1, I think the "metaclass" of a class `cls` should be understood as `type(cls)`. That way of understanding is compatible with Python's error message in the following example:

```
>>> class Meta1(type): pass
... 
>>> class Meta2(type): pass
... 
>>> def metafunc(name, bases, methods):
...     if methods.get('version') == 1:
...         return Meta1(name, bases, methods)
...     return Meta2(name, bases, methods)
... 
>>> class C1:
...     __metaclass__ = metafunc
...     version = 1
... 
>>> class C2:
...     __metaclass__ = metafunc
...     version = 2
... 
>>> type(C1)
<class '__main__.Meta1'>
>>> type(C2)
<class '__main__.Meta2'>
>>> class C3(C1,C2): pass
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

I.e., according to the error message, the metaclass of a class is a class, even though the callable used to construct the class can be just anything.

Concerning the second question, indeed with a subclass of type used as a metaclass, you can do the same as with any other callable. In particular, it is possible that it yields something that is not its instance:

```
>>> class Mockup(type):
...     def __new__(cls, name, bases, methods):
...         return Meta1(name, bases, methods)
... 
>>> class Foo:
...     __metaclass__ = Mockup
... 
>>> type(Foo)
<class '__main__.Meta1'>
>>> isinstance(Foo, Mockup)
False
>>> Foo.__metaclass__
<class '__main__.Mockup'>
```

As to why Python gives the freedom of using any callable: The previous example shows that it is actually irrelevant whether the callable is a type or not.

BTW, here is a fun example: It is possible to code metaclasses that, themselves, have a metaclass different from `type`---let's call it a metametaclass. The metametaclass implements what happens when a metaclass is called. In that way, it is possible to create a class with two bases whose metaclasses are *not* subclass of each other (compare with Python's error message in the example above!). Indeed, only the metaclass of the resulting class is subclass of the metaclass of the bases, and this metaclass is created on the fly:

```
>>> class MetaMeta(type):
...     def __call__(mcls, name, bases, methods):
...         metabases = set(type(X) for X in bases)
...         metabases.add(mcls)
...         if len(metabases) > 1:
...             mcls = type(''.join([X.__name__ for X in metabases]), tuple(metabases), {})
...         return mcls.__new__(mcls, name, bases, methods)
... 
>>> class Meta1(type):
...     __metaclass__ = MetaMeta
... 
>>> class Meta2(type):
...     __metaclass__ = MetaMeta
... 
>>> class C1:
...     __metaclass__ = Meta1
... 
>>> class C2:
...     __metaclass__ = Meta2
... 
>>> type(C1)
<class '__main__.Meta1'>
>>> type(C2)
<class '__main__.Meta2'>
>>> class C3(C1,C2): pass
... 
>>> type(C3)
<class '__main__.Meta1Meta2'>
```

What is less fun: The preceding example won't work in Python 3. If I understand correctly, Python 2 creates the class and checks whether its metaclass is a subclass of all its bases, whereas Python 3 *first* checks whether there is one base whose metaclass is superclass of the metaclasses of all other bases, and only *then* creates the new class. That's a regression, from my point of view. But that shall be the topic of a new question that I am about to post...

**Edit**: The new question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40031906/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-create-a-metaclass-for-a-class-with-several-bases)